# Is there an Javascript event for when a the page is pushed into the background?

Tags: javascript, events

I remember having used such an event, but I can't remember the name.

The specific task I'm trying to accomplish is to stop my slideshow when the browser window isn't in the foreground. I'm fading the different images with jQuery, which uses quite some CPU power.

Is there an event that tells me, when the user switches to another application / page.

Comment: @azatoth: I appreciate your edit, but I think my problem has nothing to do with jQuery besides the fact that I'm using jQuery for my UI work. The event I'm looking for is available with and without jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were some bugs with window focus event so I used mousemove event too.

```
$(window).blur(function(){
  // stop the slideshow
}).bind("focus mousemove", function(){
  // start the slideshow
});
```

Comment: Seems not to be a standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onblur (Still it's good enough for me, it's just a nice functionality to have.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "bugs" there are?

Comment: Focus event wasn't fired at some unknown cases. Sometimes were and sometimes weren't fired. I don't why is it so. Maybe ask Horatio??

Comment: @Georg: that's because of `[window|element].onblur`, as well as all other DOM level 0 event handlers, are not part of any standard (all right, they probably will be part of [HTML 5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements,-document-objects,-and-window-objects)).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the onblur event of the window to detect that change.